# Proving $\phi(G)$ is cyclic if $\phi$ : $G \to H$ is group homomorphism and $G$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Qusetion: Prove $\phi(G)$ is cyclic if $\phi$ : $G \to H$ is  group homomorphism and $G$ is cyclic
Do I do something like this to prove this: 
Let $G$ be a cyclic group and $G$=$\langle g \rangle$
Then $\phi$ : $\mathbb Z \to \langle g \rangle$ by $\phi(n)$= $g^{n}$, $n\in \mathbb Z$
 I am not sure of my approach to this. Need some help

Comment: Show that every element of $\phi(G)$ can be written as $\phi(g)^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: I do not understand how this a duplicate? My $G$ is cyclic, not a what if. I never did a surjective homomorphism either

Comment: Using the link Mr. Burde provided, you are finished: $\phi: G \to \phi(G)$ is surjective, so your question follows at once from this statement. Besides, you also have an 'if': if $G$ is cyclic and $\phi$ is a group homomorphism, then $\phi(G)$ is cyclic.

Comment: I see it but it did not pop up as a link when I was asking this question. Sorry for the duplicate folks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $G$ is cyclic, it is generated by some element $g \in G$. Let us take a closer look at $\phi(G)$: suppose $h \in \phi(G)$. This means that there is some $x \in G$ such that $\phi(x) = h$. Since $g$ generates $G$, we have that $x = g^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because of the definition of homomorphism, we have that 
$$h = \phi(x) = \phi(g^k) = \phi(g)^k$$
so $\phi(G)$ is generated by $\phi(g)$, showing that $\phi(G)$ is cyclic.

Comment: is the converse true for this? i.e., if $G$ is cyclic then subgroup of $G$ is  homomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @VKSingh: if $H$ is a subgroup of the cyclic group $G$, then we can always take the identity map restricted to $H$ and this gives a homomorphism from $H$ into $G$...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: See that if $G$ is generated by $g$ then its homomorphic image $\phi(G)$ is generated by $\phi(g)$.

Use property of homomorphism to prove the above fact.

Take an element $b\in \phi(G)$ then $\phi(a) =b,a=g^n$ then $b=\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n$.

so $\phi(G)$ is generated by $\phi(g)$, showing that $\phi(G)$ is cyclic.

Comment: I been trying to make sense of this approach and hit a wall so far

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $\phi$ acts on G. We have $\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n$.