# Showing that $g$ is a generator of $G$ implies $\phi(g)$ is a generator of $G'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G,G'$ are groups and $\phi:G\to G'$ is an isomorphism. Show that $g$ is a generator of $G$ implies $\phi(g)$ is a generator of $G'$

Comment: To start with, can you state what the sentence "$\phi(g)$ is a generator of $G'$" means?

Comment: I'm not sure cuz if I was I wouldn't've needed your help but I think it's like genertsing set of s group

Comment: That's right, it means that $\{\phi(g)\}$ is, all by itself, a generating set of $G'$.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207317/proving-phig-is-cyclic-if-phi-g-to-h-is-group-homomorphism-and-g?noredirect=1&lq=1). If $g$ is a generator of $G$, then $G=\langle g\rangle$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 4):

If $y\in G'$ there is a $x\in G$ with $\phi(x)=y$ (why?).

Since $g$ generates $G$, $g^{k}=x$  for some positive integer $k$.

Then $y=\phi(x)=\phi(g^{k}) = \phi(g)^{k}$ (why?).

Since $y$ was arbitrary, every element of $G'$ has this property.

So you may conclude...

Answer (score 2):

Since

$\phi: G \to G^\prime \tag 1$

is an isomorphism, every element of $G^\prime$ is of the form $\phi(h)$ for some $h \in G$; since $g$ generates $G$, we have

$h = g^n \tag 2$

for some $n \in \Bbb Z$; then

$\phi(h) = \phi(g^n) = (\phi(g))^n, \tag 3$

which shows that every $\phi(h) \in G^\prime$ is some power of $\phi(g)$; that is, $\phi(g)$ generates $G^\prime  = \phi(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

You wish to show that $\langle g\rangle =G\implies \langle \phi(g)\rangle =G'$, when $\phi:G\to G'$ is an isomorphism.

So let $g'\in G'$.  We need to show that $g'=\phi(g)^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

But the hypothesis that $\phi$ is an isomorphism implies there is $h\in G$ with $\phi(h)=g'$.  Now since $g$ generates $G$, we know there is $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $g^n=h$.

Then since $\phi$ is a homomorphism,  $g'=\phi(h)=\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n\square $